# Controlling vertical space in embedded tabu environment

Tags: spacing, tabu

When using embedded `tabu` environments I have difficulties having different vertical space in the outer and inner tables. Consider these simple embedded `tabu` tables:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabu}{|c|}
    \hline
    \begin{tabu}{l|c|r}
      left & {\LARGE \textbf{MIDDLE}} & right
    \end{tabu} \\
    \hline
    \begin{tabu}{l|c|r}
      left & {\LARGE \textbf{MIDDLE}} & right
    \end{tabu} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

The table renders like this:

[image: Large text too close to hline]

As you can see, the large text is too close to the upper `\hline`. To fix this I try to use the `\tabulinesep` command before the first/outer table:

(I use a large 5pt spacing to make it obvious what happens.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
  \tabulinesep=^5pt % <==== At least 5pt above text.
  \begin{tabu}{|c|}
    \hline
    \begin{tabu}{l|c|r}
      left & {\LARGE \textbf{MIDDLE}} & right
    \end{tabu} \\
    \hline
    \begin{tabu}{l|c|r}
      left & {\LARGE \textbf{MIDDLE}} & right
    \end{tabu} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

However, it leaves gaps above the vertical rules (lines) as the `\tabulinesep` also applies to the outer table:

[image: Gaps above vertical rules]

To fix it, I can use a `\tabulinesep` command right above the two innner tables where it should apply like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabu}{|c|}
    \hline
    \tabulinesep=^5pt % <==== At least 5pt above text in inner table.
    \begin{tabu}{l|c|r}
      left & {\LARGE \textbf{MIDDLE}} & right
    \end{tabu} \\
    \hline
    \tabulinesep=^5pt % <==== At least 5pt above text in inner table.
    \begin{tabu}{l|c|r}
      left & {\LARGE \textbf{MIDDLE}} & right
    \end{tabu} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Which renders the correct result:

[image: Correct spacing in innner tables]

However, I do not want to repeat myself for each inner table. So what I really want is to set a global default, and then make an exception for the outer table. My guess would be this but it does not work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\global\tabulinesep=^5pt % <=== Global setting

\begin{document}
  \tabulinesep=^0pt % <==== Cannot override for outer table only... :-(
  \begin{tabu}{|c|}
    \hline
    \begin{tabu}{l|c|r}
      left & {\LARGE \textbf{MIDDLE}} & right
    \end{tabu} \\
    \hline
    \begin{tabu}{l|c|r}
      left & {\LARGE \textbf{MIDDLE}} & right
    \end{tabu} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

The result is the first image (where I started out).

Any suggestions for setting a global `\tabusep` and then override it for the outer table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert a strut, just for its height part in case only uppercase is used. I show both examples.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for a better \smash
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabu}{|c|}
    \hline
    \begin{tabu}{l|c|r}
      left & \LARGE\smash[b]{\strut}\textbf{MIDDLE} & right
    \end{tabu} \\
    \hline
    \begin{tabu}{l|c|r}
      left & \LARGE\strut\textbf{MIDDLEg} & right
    \end{tabu} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Elegant solution (I did not know of neither `\smash` nor the amsmath version of `\smash`) even though it does not really answer my question (maybe because what I ask is not possible?)

Comment: Ok, I ended up using your solution since it also gives nice font size dependent spacing from the top rule. However, I ran into another problem which I will post as a separate question.

Comment: I posted the additional question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207850/16761