# Smashed strut in tabu environment causes too much extra vertical space

Tags: spacing, tabu

## Problem

I have a `tabu` table where the text in one column is larger than the text in the rest of the table. To avoid the text to come to close to the top rule I insert a strut (where the bottom has been smashed) in the relevant cell (as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207788/16761)).

However, it seems that the `\smash[b]{\strut}` causes unintended extra vertical space to be inserted unless inserted inside the `\textbf{}`.

If I use an ordinary `\strut` (including the decending `0.3\baselineskip`) or if I create the *smashed strut* manually using a `\rule{0pt}{0.7\baselineskip}` (which should have the same dimensions} it seems to work fine no matter where I place it.

Can somebody explain why it matters whether the `\smash[b]{\strut}` is inserted inside or outside a `\textbf{}` block?

## Example

Here is a simple example demonstrating the behaviour. First the result and then the LaTeX source.

### Result

[image: Various attempts to fix vertical space in tabu environment]

### LaTeX source

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, width=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  Large text in \verb$tabu$ environment is too close to the uppermost line:

  \begin{tabu}{|c|}
    \hline
    \begin{tabu} {lX[c]r}
      left & {\LARGE\textbf{MIDDLE}} & right
    \end{tabu} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabu}

  To fix it we insert a smashed strut \emph{outside} the \verb$\textbf$ block but it does not look nice:

  \begin{tabu}{|c|}
    \hline
    \begin{tabu} {lX[c]r}
      left & {\LARGE\smash[b]{\strut}\textbf{MIDDLE}} & right
    \end{tabu} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabu}

  Putting the smashed strut \emph{inside} \verb$\textbf$ apparently works:

  \begin{tabu}{|c|}
    \hline
    \begin{tabu} {lX[c]r}
      left & {\LARGE\textbf{\smash[b]{\strut}MIDDLE}} & right
    \end{tabu} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabu}

  If the strut is not smashed it works \emph{outside} \verb$\textbf$:

  \begin{tabu}{|c|}
    \hline
    \begin{tabu} {lX[c]r}
      left & {\LARGE\strut\textbf{MIDDLE}} & right
    \end{tabu} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabu}

  If the smashed strut is replaced by a \verb$\rule$ is also works:

  \begin{tabu}{|c|}
    \hline
    \begin{tabu} {lX[c]r}
      left & {\LARGE\textbf{\rule{0pt}{0.7\baselineskip}MIDDLE}} & right
    \end{tabu} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference between an `X` and a `c` column. The latter is typeset as if it were `\makebox[<dimen>]{<text>}` (the `<dimen>` is automatically computed, while the former is `\parbox{<dimen>}{<text>}` (the text will be centered because of the `c` option to `X`).

While a `\smash` gives no problem in a horizontal box (`\makebox`), it doesn't start a paragraph in a `\parbox`. Use `\leavevmode` before `\smash` in case of doubts.

As you noticed `\rule` works. A different workaround than using `\smash[b]` might indeed be

```
\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox}
```

which might be a bit mysterious for the uninitiated.

The `\strut` works when inside `\textbf` because this macro starts a paragraph.

The input I'd prefer would be

```
\begin{tabu}{|c|}
\hline
\begin{tabu} {lX[c]r}
left & {\LARGE\leavevmode\smash[b]{\strut}\bfseries MIDDLE} & right
\end{tabu} \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
```

In case you need this in several places, you could define a new command.

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tabustrut}{o}
 {%
  \leavevmode\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\smash{\strut}}{\smash[#1]{\strut}}%
 }
```

so you could use `\tabustrut` for `\leavevmode\smash{\strut}` and `\tabustrut[b]` for `\leavevmode\smash[b]{\strut}`. There's no problem in using `\leavevmode` in a `c` column, it will do nothing.

[image]

Comment: Excellent explanation! So AFAIK `\leavemode` means exit vertical mode and go to horizontal mode. Without `\leavemode` (in the X column which is a parbox) the smashed strut is stacked (in vertical mode) on top of the text. Is that correctly understoood?

Comment: @mgd That's exactly what happens.